# Error while creating a external table using JSON jars in hive 13.0

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am doing some testing on hive 13.0. I am trying to create a external table and using json jars to read the json formatted data file. But getting errors. Below is my create table statment

```
'$response = Invoke-Hive -Query @"
add jar wasb://path/json-serde-1.1.9.2.jar;
add jar wasb://path/json-serde-1.1.9.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (col1 string, col2 string...coln int)
PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ()
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
"@'
```

below is the error i am getting

```
'FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.object inspector.primitive.AbstractPrimitiveJavaObjectInspector.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive
```

/PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils$PrimitiveTypeEntry;)V'

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would say you might be having some datatypes in your table which cannot be used to with the Serde. Could you post the details of all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes needed to that SerDe for Hive .13 - you can see a list here: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/pull/64

Comment: it usually preferred to add snippets of the key information from web site linked into a question